# Magnolia WAR produces error in publishing module

Tags: magnolia

I downloaded the magnolia-community-demo-webapp with tomcat from this link
https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Developing/Bundles-and-webapps.html
and found the public instance folder almost empty.

I then downloaded the magnolia-community-demo-webapp WAR from the same link and deployed it. It works but when I click the publishing module to get the code to be used in the author it generates a null pointer exception error.

```
Message: Failed to create instance of [class info.magnolia.publishing.app.PublishingMainSubApp]. Stack trace: info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: Failed to create instance of [class info.magnolia.publishing.app.PublishingMainSubApp]
    at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(GuiceComponentProvider.java:138)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiComponentProvider.lambda$newInstanceWithParameterResolvers$3(UiComponentProvider.java:137)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiComponentProvider.provideInCurrentScope(UiComponentProvider.java:177)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(UiComponentProvider.java:137)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiComponentProvider.newInstance(UiComponentProvider.java:128)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.AppInstanceControllerImpl.startSubApp(AppInstanceControllerImpl.java:421)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.AppInstanceControllerImpl.openSubApp(AppInstanceControllerImpl.java:369)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.BaseApp.lambda$openSubApp$7(BaseApp.java:138)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at info.magnolia.util.OptionalConsumer.ifPresent(OptionalConsumer.java:56)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.BaseApp.openSubApp(BaseApp.java:138)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.BaseApp.start(BaseApp.java:111)
    at info.magnolia.publishing.app.PublishingBaseApp.start(PublishingBaseApp.java:56)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.AppInstanceControllerImpl.start(AppInstanceControllerImpl.java:220)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.AppControllerImpl.doStartIfNotAlreadyRunning(AppControllerImpl.java:278)
    at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.AppControllerImpl.onLocationChanged(AppControllerImpl.java:415)
    at info.magnolia.ui.api.location.LocationChangedEvent.dispatch(LocationChangedEvent.java:64)
    at info.magnolia.ui.api.location.LocationChangedEvent.dispatch(LocationChangedEvent.java:42)
    at info.magnolia.event.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:75)
    at info.magnolia.event.ResettableEventBus.fireEvent(ResettableEventBus.java:70)
    at info.magnolia.ui.api.location.LocationController.goToWithoutChecks(LocationController.java:135)
    at info.magnolia.ui.api.location.LocationController.goTo(LocationController.java:115)
    at info.magnolia.admincentral.findbar.FindBar.openApp(FindBar.java:278)
    at info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.applauncher.AppLauncher$1.openApp(AppLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:447)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:412)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:275)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1637)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:464)
    at info.magnolia.admincentral.AdmincentralServlet.service(AdmincentralServlet.java:119)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ServletDispatchingFilter.doFilter(ServletDispatchingFilter.java:148)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:75)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Bypass.processCacheRequest(Bypass.java:58)
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.CompositeExecutor.processCacheRequest(CompositeExecutor.java:66)
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:164)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.virtualuri.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:102)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:78)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cors.AbstractCorsFilter.doFilter(AbstractCorsFilter.java:77)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:94)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.module.site.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:119)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:74)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    at info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:128)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:155)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:128)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:75)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:107)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:110)
    at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: Failed to create an instance with c-tor [PublishingMainSubApp(SubAppContext, PublishingPresenter)]
    at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:131)
    at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:99)
    at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(GuiceComponentProvider.java:134)
    ... 124 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:129)
    ... 126 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vaadin.v7.data.util.ObjectProperty.<init>(ObjectProperty.java:58)
    at info.magnolia.publishing.app.PublishingPresenter.createDataSource(PublishingPresenter.java:97)
    at info.magnolia.publishing.app.PublishingPresenter.start(PublishingPresenter.java:87)
    at info.magnolia.publishing.app.PublishingMainSubApp.<init>(PublishingMainSubApp.java:48)
    ... 131 more
```

How can I run a public instance to publish content from the author?

Answer (score 1):

Just install the bundle you have downloaded fully. When you download it, indeed the public folder is nearly empty, but that's because content is copied in during the installation. Just install the bundle fully to have it configured properly.
Otherwise if you install instances separately on your own, you need to also manually configure them to be aware of each other and to make publishing work.
More details on configuration and on creating new public instances is in the [documentation](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Administration/Instances/Creating-a-new-public-instance.html).

Comment: Why is the publishing module generating an error from the bundle or from the war?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your config, but it seems like your instance is missing something, which should not be the case with default bundle when installation ran without any errors. Perhaps you should delete everything and start the installation again? Also not sure what you mean by "to get the code to be used in the author".

Comment: I was mistaken and thought the public code goes into the author. It is the other way around. The thing is even on the default bundle when the public is configured correctly and publishing works fine between the two instances. Clicking on publishing tools on the public generates an error.

Comment: Good catch. Logged as https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/PUBLISHING-179